# Download zipalign para o Mac

Tags: android, android-studio, download, arquivo-zip, assinatura-digital

Olá! Acabo de assinar um aplicativo teste no **Android Studio** e gostaria de fazer upload dele no **Google Play**.

Andei pesquisando e vi que o **zipalign** facilita o processo de importar o **APK**, porém, localizei apenas disponibilidade de download para Windows.

Alguém sabe me falar como consigo fazer download do **zipalign** para o Mac?

Comment: O zipalign é parte* do processo pra se gerar o apk, ele alinha todos os recursos não comprimidos do apk para ficarem mais fáceis para o Android carregá-los na memória (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html). Se não me engano o zipalign fica dentro do sdk do Android na pasta `tools` ou `platform-tools`.

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento, vou validar @Wakim

Comment: Ah não, acabei vendo agora, ele fica em: `android-sdk/build-tools/<versao>/zipalign`.

Comment: Vi uns tutoriais onde o zipalign era baixado via download. Esse caminho é indiferente para Mac e Windows, correto? @Wakim

Comment: Sim, ele é parte da versão do `build-tools` que você baixa pelo sdk manager e é independente de OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usar o  zipalign faz parte* do processo pra se gerar o apk, ele alinha todos os recursos não comprimidos do apk para ficarem mais fáceis para o Android carregá-los na memória usando [`mmap()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) ([developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html)).

A localização dele é: `android-sdk/build-tools/<versao>/zipalign`

* Fazer parte não significa que é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática.